# 4 wire hot tub circuit installed but I only need a 3 wire

Tags: wiring, hot-tub

I have a 240v/60amp four wire hot tub circuit.  Two black wires, one white and one green.  The hot tub we are installing only needs three wires black, red and green.  I assume the two black wires are hot.  Do I just hook the two back wires to the red and black connections, the green to the ground connection and then just cap off the white/neutral wire?

Comment: You got a good install, it allows you to connect almost anything you want.

Comment: Even better is to use all 4 wires and instead of a simple disconnect, put in an actual subpanel (cost maybe $100 extra - very little compared to the entire project). Then you can wire up separate circuits for lighting, convenience receptacles (check for minimum distance from the hot tub), etc.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. The hot tub requires only 240 volts but not 120 volts so there is no need to connect the neutral.